# How to return results with sequelize.js?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
var userid = 7;
var um;

sequelize.query("select user_money from ecs_users u where u.user_id = ?", {replacements: [userid], type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}).then(function(data) {
  console.log('Inside um is '+data[0].user_money);
  um = data[0].user_money;
});

//how to get the result at here ???
console.log('Outside um is '+um);
console.log('testtesttest');
```

**result**

```
Outside um is undefined

testtesttest

info: Executing (default): select user_money from ecs_users u where u.user_id = 7

Inside um is 0.01
```

How to get the result in outside?

Answer (score 0):

`sequelize.query()` is an asynchronous function. If you want to use the result, you should do it inside the promise chain, not outside. You don't have anyway to reliably know how long `query()` will take to run.

If you absolutely must use it outside the promise chain, create a Boolean that tells you whether or not you have the result yet. Set the Boolean to true only once you have the result inside the promise chain. Outside the promise chain, you can check the value of the Boolean and make a decision whether you want to wait (e.g., use `setTimeout()` to try again) or ignore or throw an error or something else.

Comment: sequelize.query() donot have a synchronous function ?

Comment: Synchronous functions will lock up your main thread. That might be OK if you never have more than one person using your app simultaneously. But since that's not typical, many Node.js libraries don't bother with synchronous functions at all as they end up being both dangerous and unnecessary.